Delphi/Android application error : "Unsupported Media Type"
I made a multi-platform applet with Delphi 11.3. I'm using the TNetHTTPClient component to POST an XML formatted text to a REST API. Running it in Win32 mode works fine. Running it in Android mode throws an error:

Unsupported Media Type

Here is the code:
procedure TForm13.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HttpClient: TNetHTTPClient;
  Response: IHTTPResponse;
  URL,user,key,XML, AFM: string;
  s, F : TstringStream;
  FormData: TMultipartFormData;
  XMLData: TBytesStream;
  PostData: TBytes;
begin
  HttpClient := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
  try
      URL := 'https://www1.gsis.gr/wsaade/RgWsPublic2/RgWsPublic2?WSDL';
      XML := '<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns2="http://rgwspublic2/RgWsPublic2Service" xmlns:ns3="http://rgwspublic2/RgWsPublic2">'
            +'   <env:Header>'
            +'      <ns1:Security>'
            +'         <ns1:UsernameToken>'
            +'            <ns1:Username>username</ns1:Username>'
            +'            <ns1:Password>key</ns1:Password>'
            +'         </ns1:UsernameToken>'
            +'      </ns1:Security>'
            +'   </env:Header>'
            +'   <env:Body>'
            +'      <ns2:rgWsPublic2AfmMethod>'
            +'         <ns2:INPUT_REC>'
            +'            <ns3:afm_called_by/>'
            +'            <ns3:afm_called_for>'+AFM+'</ns3:afm_called_for>'
            +'            <ns3:as_on_date>'+formatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd',date)+'</ns3:as_on_date>'
            +'         </ns2:INPUT_REC>'
            +'      </ns2:rgWsPublic2AfmMethod>'
            +'   </env:Body>'
            +'</env:Envelope>';
            s := TstringStream.create(UTF8encode(XML));
       Response := HttpClient.Post(URL, s, nil); // succeeds in win32, fails in Android
     //  Response := HttpClient.Post(URL, s, nil, [TNetHeader.Create('Content-Type', 'text/xml')]); // fails in both platforms
    if Response.StatusCode = 200 then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Text := Response.ContentAsString();
    end
    else
    begin
      ShowMessage('Error: ' + Response.StatusCode.ToString + ' - ' + Response.StatusText);
    end;
  finally
    HttpClient.Free;
  end;
end;

I have tried to post as TMultipartFormData or as XMLData := TBytesStream.Create(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XML)) or as Response := HttpClient.Post(URL, s, nil, [TNetHeader.Create('Content-Type', 'text or application/xml')]) but it always fails.

Not related to your error, but FYI TStringStream.Create(UTF8encode(XML)) does not do what you think it does since 2009. TStringString takes a UTF16 encoded UnicodeString but UTF8Encode() returns a UTF8 encoded RawByteString. The RTL will decode the UTF8 back to UTF16 before TStringString ever sees it, and then the TStringStream will encode the UnicodeStringusingTEncoding.Defaultinstead. To put a UTF8 encoded string into aTStringStream, use this instead: TStringStream.Create(XML, TEncoding.UTF8)`

Do you have the same problem if you use the HttpClient.ContentType property instead of using the AHeaders parameter of Post()?

I put s := TStringStream.Create(XML, TEncoding.UTF8) and HttpClient.ContentType = text/xml or application/xml but the same problem. In win32 works.

Have you tried looking at the raw HTTP data to see what is actually different when sent on different platforms? Sounds like a bug you should report to Embarcadero.

With Fiddler tool I see that client sends exactly the same raw data in Win32 and Android except that, in Android, sends additionally the instruction "Accept-Encoding: gzip".

That alone would not cause an "Unsupported Media Type" error. That header simply means the client gives permission to the server to send the response in a compressed form if the server decides to do so. So, something else is going on to cause the error. You may have to contact the server admin to diagnose why the error is being sent.

I finally overcame the problem with the following solution which assumes, however, that we have access to our own server.

I saved to my server a php file (post2otherServer.php) with content:
<?php
$url      = $_SERVER['HTTP_URL'];
$username = $_SERVER['HTTP_NAME'];
$password = $_SERVER['HTTP_KEY'];
$XML      = file_get_contents('php://input');
$ch = curl_init($url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $XML);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/xml',  // Inform the server the data is XML
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($XML),
    'user: '.$username,        // Custom header for username
    'Key: '.$password         // Custom header for password
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo htmlspecialchars($response);
}
curl_close($ch);
?>


I execute the code
s := TstringStream.create(UTF8encode(XML));
Response := POST('https://myserver.gr/post2otherServer.php',
                s,nil,[TNetHeader.Create('URL',otherServer),
                        TNetHeader.Create('NAME',user),
                         TNetHeader.Create('KEY',pass)]);
res := Response.ContentAsString;


The job done! my server acts as a proxy and it doesn't seem to deal with the "Unsupported Media Type" issue.


